# upload files to centOs

Tags: windows, centos, hyper-v

How can I upload files to centOs linux that are  on hyper-v on the host windows server 2012? I know that I can use fileZilla or whatever ftp client. Is there a way to upload it without installing ftp client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

scp [from] [to]

```
scp user@homeip:/path/to/file /local/path/
```

If you want to upload a folder :

```
scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/foo /home/user/Desktop/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the scp command,it's based on the ssh protocol

Answer (score 0):

you can share a folder on your windows and mount that folder inside your centOS.

if your windows is member of domain use this

```
mount //WindowsIP/ShareFolder /mnt/ -o username=username,dom=domainname
```

otherwise

```
mount //WindowsIP/ShareFolder /mnt/ -o username=username
```

to use scp command you need to have a bash client on your windows.